# Should we edit questions that refer to old documentation but are still relevant for the latest version?

Tags: discussion, edits

As the title reads, here goes a concrete example: [Python comparison operators chaining/grouping left to right?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/25753474/3767239). The question points to documentation for Python 2 which won't be maintained past [January 1, 2020](https://pythonclock.org/) however it is equally relevant for Python 3 which is likely the relevant version for most users visiting this question. The documentation, and the quoted part in particular, have been slightly modified from version 2 to 3. Clearly the links within the documentation itself further point visitors to the up-to-date version of content.

So should we edit such questions, updating links to documentation and any derived quotes, to match the latest version, if the question is still relevant in this new context and the edit will bring neither the question nor the answers out of their original context?

Comment: Does "won't be maintained" imply "all documentation links will subsequently break"?

Comment: @Makoto The documentation will persist. But the fact that it won't be maintained means that more and more users (and probably "most" already now), searching for that topic, are users of Python 3 and hence I'd suppose they want to see this topic being discussed in the context of the version they are using and similarly would like to be pointed to relevant documentation. Especially newcomers and new projects are almost certainly concerned with Python 3. Having a still relevant topic point to Python 2 documentation might be confusing for a lot of users (especially if they further explore it).

Comment: Let's not conflate the language being no longer maintained/supported with the documentation no longer being maintained/supported.  Just because the language is EOL doesn't mean that the documentation isn't relevant to someone who has to run old Python 2 code on some Godforsaken server because no one wants to upgrade it.  Also, there's nothing obviously sticking out at me which indicates that we should take action until the Python project actively starts breaking links to their own documentation for Python 2, which...wouldn't make much sense.

Comment: As a for-instance, Oracle [still provides a way](https://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/archive-139210.html) for you to get documentation for Java all the way back to 1.1.  Python's path isn't clear in my head as to what they plan to do, so I'd rather not expend energy on a circumstance *today* which isn't an actual issue *today*.

Comment: Besides, this is a golden opportunity for a savvy engineer to prove that they're not *just* plugging whatever they found on Stack Overflow into their application and being surprised that it doesn't work...